# Spawning objects above the canvas in random locations doesn't work on all devices

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to spawn objects above the canvas on a random Y axis (which works fine) and a random X axis which only works on my PC. When I do it on my phone the objects don't spawn above the canvas, they spawn on only the left side of the screen and I'm assuming off the screen to the left. Does anyone know what is causing this to happen?

Comment: Can you provide some information about your canvas setup? How does it scale with screen size? Are you testing on the PC with the same screen ratio as your phone's?

Comment: The Canvas scales with screen size (matching height) and I and I am using 16:9 ratio but I don't know if that's the same for my phone. I'll find out and get back to you. I'm not very good with hardware and I want this to work on all mobile phones, not just my one (I don't know if I needed to clarify that or not, sorry) EDIT: my phone is 360 x 780

Comment: Try setting the unity's game view to that same resolution or at least aspect ratio (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GameView.html under Aspect) and see if you get the same results as on your phone.

Comment: I've done it and uploaded the new version to my phone. It's fine on my PC but still not on my phone.

Comment: You've set the game view in Unity to your phone's resolution, everything appears correctly, but on your phone it doesn't? Can you google if other people with your phone have similar issues?

Comment: Nobody else seems to have the same problem. Either that or I can't find anything.